# why ubuntu touch terminal cannot execute app

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch

my buntu phone is nexus 4. The following code is not being executed.

#### Code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### Compile

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -static -o hello main.c
```

- I copy files to `/home/phablet/Downloads` directory
- open  ubuntu phone Terminal ,
- Modify file attributes (`chmod a+x ./hello`)
- execute `./hello`

but ubuntu phone Prompt gives the following error

```
./hello permission denied
```

why?

Comment: What type of file is _hello_ exactly?

Comment: Does Ubuntu Phone use an ext4 file system? Check if your `chmod` took effect: `ls -l  hello`.

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 phablet phablet 589420 Dec  2 08:59 hello

Comment: and if you run e.g. `bash ./hello`?

Comment: its not only you. you can run binaries if you ssh into the machine (or localhost, if on the phone). otherwise you cant run binaries in $HOME :S

Comment: Is there anything in "sudo dmesg" immediately after you run the command indicating an issue?

Comment: I just tried with git. Seems to me that the apparmor profile for the terminal prevents running binaries from the home directory of the user: [140792.471956] type=1400 audit(1431182253.050:175): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" profile="com.ubuntu.terminal_terminal_0.7.70" name="/home/phablet/apps/git/usr/bin/git" pid=28134 comm="bash" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=32011 ouid=32011

Answer (score 6):

I figured something out. The reason you can't run binaries from your home directory is that the apparmor profile of the terminal prevents it. If you look at the dmesg output after trying to run a binary you should see something like this:

```
[140792.471956] type=1400 audit(1431182253.050:175): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" profile="com.ubuntu.terminal_terminal_0.7.70" name="/home/phablet/apps/git/usr/bin/git" pid=28134 comm="bash" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=32011 ouid=32011
```

Which just tells you that apparmor denied the terminal to run your program, and among other things it tells you the apparmor profile name (com.ubuntu.terminal_terminal_0.7.70) of the terminal. To allow running arbitrary binaries we need to change that profile.

Now normally you'd find apparmor profiles under /etc/apparmor.d but this is not always the case on ubuntu phone. It seems especially click packages (which the terminal is one of) do their own thing and put files in different places. I found multiple locations for the terminal apparmor profile and the right one to edit seems to be:

```
sudo vi /var/lib/apparmor/profiles/click_com.ubuntu.terminal_terminal_0.7.70
```

There should be a section like this:

```
# autopilot runs things in out of ~/autopilot/fakeenv, so lets allow running
# things pretty much everywhere but avoid exec conflicts with the autopilot
# include file which has this rule:
# owner @{HOMEDIRS}/autopilot/fakeenv/*/.local/share/@{APP_PKGNAME}/** mrwklix,
/[^h]** pix,
/[^h][^o][^m][^e]** pix,
@{HOMEDIRS}/*/autopilot/[^f][^a][^k][^e]*/** pix,
```

Which should already allow pretty much everything to be executed under /home if I understand it correclty. The comment seems to imply the same. Still, for reasons that escape me, it does not work. So to make it work, you can just remove (or comment out) this whole section and replace it with:

```
/** pix,
```

That should allow the terminal app to always run everything, from everywhere. Afterwards restart apparmor:

```
sudo service apparmor restart
```

and you should be good to go.