# How should I install Git on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-touch, git, aquaris, bq

I've got a nice little BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition here and I'm trying it out. Is there a sensible way to install Git on it? It doesn't appear to be available via the default repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I found so far is to just download the armhf build of git from launchpad, extract it on my desktop and copy the contents to my phone. Then I can just run the git binary from where I have it copied to.

The latest armhf builds for git can be found here:

```
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/armhf/git/
```

Download the deb of one of the builds and extract it (either with file-roller or with dpkg -x). After you extracted the deb, you'll have, among others, a usr/ dir which should contain everything you need to run git.

Upload that dir to your phone, so that its in your home, then just run

```
/home/phablet/usr/bin/git
```

and it should work. It'll complain about not finding templates when you do git init, but you can run it with

```
env GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR=/home/phablet/usr/share/git-core/templates /home/phablet/usr/bin/git init
```

to fix that problem.

If you don't want to type the full path every time you want to run git, you can set an alias in your .bashrc:

```
alias git=/home/phablet/usr/bin/git
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this! This looks promising. I've followed your instructions, but have run into a problem actually executing the git executable. When I try to run it with the standard user or sudo, I get ```Permission denied```. I note that the file's permissions are ```-rwxr-xr-x```. Would you happen to know what to try next?

Comment: Ah, thats interesting. I only used git over ssh so far, and then it works. Now I just tried to run git with the terminal on the phone, and then I get the same error. So, I don't really now what the problem is yet. Here is a related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/556041/why-ubuntu-touch-terminal-cannot-execute-app

Comment: Just answered the other question which also applies here. In short: apparmor prevents the terminal from executing arbitrary binaries, you can work around that by changing its apparmor profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try unlocking the Ubuntu file system first:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount, rw /
```

Then deleting the lock files to install applications:

```
$ sudo rm -f  /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
$ sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Comment: Using the word "try"  makes this a comment not an answer ;-)

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for your help. I've tried your suggestions, but I'm still getting a permission denied message when I try to execute. I've tried also the command ```sudo mount -o remount, exec /```, but this didn't work either. Would you have any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Rinzwind over to you ;)