# how to install nodeJs on an m10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nodejs

I'm making some raspberry/nodeJS powered project, and i wanted a way to code on the go, so i though convergence was the way to go, and i bought a m10.

I managed to get git working following the instructions here [How should I install Git on Ubuntu Touch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613655/how-should-i-install-git-on-ubuntu-touch)

I found a text editor i'll try named seabass.

The last thing i need to be happy is to make nodeJS work, preferably the last version. 
Since i've read that doing apt-get is a bad idea, i tried to use the same process as for git, but when i launch it, i get a missing library error. So i tried to find it on the same place as the git and node binaries, put it in the lib folder, and then, another missing lib error, find it again, and get a third, and i can't find the third one (libicui18n.48.so)

Is there a better way to do this ?
Probably yes, but i can't find it, and help will be very welcome :)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f` fixes missing packages. :)

Comment: Seeing your comment gave me the will to try `sudo apt-get install nodeJS` despite what i read elsewhere, and maybe i misread and it was just for `sudo apt-get install` alone, or older version but it seems to work and i manage to execute nodeJs. i'll do more testing tonight and provide an answer if all is good.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to install it in a libertine container that way you don't have to worry about the issues with no being able to execute binaries from your home directory. Going to try it out myself soon, I'll add an answer if it all works out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more testing, executing of one project and getting a node_module trough npm, I can say that using the method described here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/ do work, without needed any further config.

> ```
> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
> sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
> ```
>
> Alternatively, for Node.js v6:
>
> ```
> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
> sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
> ```
>
> *Optional:* install build tools: To compile and install native add-ons from npm you may also need to install build tools:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
> ```

I have node, I have git, and vi, and I'm happy with Ubuntu Touch :)

Edit because i just found this post, and think it's revelant and important to add to this response.

[Consequences of using apt-get in ubuntu touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600065/consequences-of-using-apt-get-in-ubuntu-touch)

So it work, but there can be consequences.